# Delete dynamically-generated table row using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

the code below add and remove table row with the help of Jquery 
 the add function works fine but the remove only work if I remove the **first row**

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td><button type="button"  class="removebutton" title="Remove this row">X</button>
</td> 
         <td><input type="text" id="txtTitle" name="txtTitle"></td> 
         <td><input type="text" id="txtLink" name="txtLink"></td> 
    </tr>
</table>
<button id ="addbutton">Add Row</button>
```

and the script

```
 var i = 1;
$("#addbutton").click(function() {
  $("table tr:first").clone().find("input").each(function() {
    $(this).val('').attr({
      'id': function(_, id) {return id + i },
      'name': function(_, name) { return name + i },
      'value': ''               
    });
  }).end().appendTo("table");
  i++;
});

$('button.removebutton').on('click',function() {
    alert("aa");
  $(this).closest( 'tr').remove();
  return false;
});
```

can anyone give me the explanation why  I can only remove the first row ?
thank so much

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to use event delegation because those buttons don't exist on load:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/Z7fG7/1/

```
 $(document).on('click', 'button.removebutton', function () { // <-- changes
     alert("aa");
     $(this).closest('tr').remove();
     return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use Event Delegation, because of the fact that you are creating dynamic rows.

```
$(document).on('click','button.removebutton', function() {
    alert("aa");
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  return false;
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CMy5f/)

Answer (score 3):

When cloning, by default it will not clone the events.  The added rows do not have an event handler attached to them.  If you call `clone(true)` then it should handle them as well.

http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: @isherwood - it's only recently that I've come across your style of event delegation.  I was always attaching events immediately after creating objects.  I like your way because I could have a section of code where I group all my event handling right up front.  Is it a matter of personal preference, or is one way more standard than the other?

Comment: I'd say it's situation-dependent. What's more clear to the next developer stumbling through your code?

Comment: Fair enough.  I would just rather not set it up pre-stumbled.  :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is encapsulate code of button event in a function, and call it when you add TRs too:

```
 var i = 1;
$("#addbutton").click(function() {
  $("table tr:first").clone().find("input").each(function() {
    $(this).val('').attr({
      'id': function(_, id) {return id + i },
      'name': function(_, name) { return name + i },
      'value': ''               
    });
  }).end().appendTo("table");
  i++;

  applyRemoveEvent();  
});


function applyRemoveEvent(){
    $('button.removebutton').on('click',function() {
        alert("aa");
      $(this).closest( 'tr').remove();
      return false;
    });
};

applyRemoveEvent();
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/Z7fG7/2/**

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I've used a function similar to this...

```
deleteRow: function (ctrl) {

    //remove the row from the table
    $(ctrl).closest('tr').remove();

}
```

... with markup like this ...

```
<tr>
<td><span id="spDeleteRow" onclick="deleteRow(this)">X</td>
<td> blah blah </td>
</tr>
```

...and it works fine

Answer (score -1):

```
  $(document.body).on('click', 'buttontrash', function () { // <-- changes
    alert("aa");
   /$(this).closest('tr').remove();
    return false;
});
```

This works perfectly, take not of document.body

Comment: Sorry, but this is a direct copy of Wilfredo's but it won't work either. You have half of a comment.